# White Stripe on images in css?

Tags: css

I need to make white stripes on an image Like  [this](http://hess.com/sustainability/default.aspx) on header image there are children's and there is some white stripe. same white stripes can be show on below sustainability report image.Although they are using image which had these stripes. Any idea how it can be implement in css or css3 with any image.

Answer (score 3):

This or some variant of it ought to work:

HTML:

```
<div class="image"><img src="whatever-you-like.gif"><div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image { position: relative; }
.image div { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(stripes.png); }
```

Stripes.png must be a 24-bit PNG image with a low alpha value.

Note that in this implementation you don't have to use your original image as a CSS background, you can use the image tag as normal (just with some extra HTML around it).

Comment: +1 actually, you shouldn't use the image as background. otherwise, the containing div won't have height and will display nothing. placing it in an `<img>` gives height to the containing div.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your original image as a background, and on top of it use .png image with these stipes and transparency.